# Issue with implementing Smart Target. Ambientdatacontext.CurrentClaimStore is returning null value

Tags: smarttarget

I am trying to fetch trigger type using Smart Target API. Code I have used is as below

```
ClaimStore claimStore = AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore;
if (claimStore != null)
{
     string query = AmbientDataHelper.GetTriggers(claimStore);
}
```

Everytime it is returning claimstore as null. Can anyone suggest if I am missing anything..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't mentioned what context the code is running in. If it is always null, the only conclusion I can make is that the Ambient Data Framework isn't running in that context (e.g. maybe you are running this code outside of a web server that has the ADF filter/module configured).

Check the log files to troubleshoot the issue and follow the [steps in the documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B513935A-2C58-42F3-A958-FB3E620C7812) if you need to set up the ADF.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Root cause of the issue was Ambient data framework was not configured in my website.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: It is Tridion 2013 SP1. Smart Target I was using 2014.